# Can I compile one .tex file into multiple PDF using TeXMaker, beamer class?

Tags: beamer, xetex, compiling, multiple-files

So, let's suppose I have this presentation here

```
\documentclass{beamer}                  

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is frame 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
This is frame 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
This is frame 3
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
This is frame 4
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
This is frame 5
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
This is frame 6
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Using XeLaTeX, I'd like to produce multiple PDFs from this file. For example, how could I make one PDF with slides 1 and 2, another one with slides 3 and 4 and a last one with slides 5 and 6? And of course, I'm asking how would one do that without creating multiple `.tex` files.

Comment: unrelated but do not use inputenc with xetex

Comment: Oh man, you're right. Let me edit that.

Comment: See if `\includeonlyframes{<name 1>,<name >}` and naming frames as `\frame[label=name 1]`,  `\frame[label=name 2]`, `\frame[label=name 3]`, etc.